# How can I ensure both randomly generated colors are not the same?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm making a simple game where two shapes change colors repeatedly using a timer, I have an array of colors to choose from how can I make sure both shapes will have be colored differently?

My code:

```
property variant colorArray: ["#008499","#963A65","#01FF97","#FF4140"] //colors to choose from
Timer{
        id: color_switch
        interval: 1000; running: true; repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            shape1.color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]
            shape2.color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to get second color index so many times it is different. Note that in theory random indices could always be the same so you would never get past the while loop :)

```
onTriggered: {
    var index1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
    var index2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
    while (index1 === index2) {
        index2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)
    }
    shape1.color = colorArray[index1]
    shape2.color = colorArray[index2]
}
```

Better approach might be that after selecting color1 you create a copy of the array without color1 and then get color2 from the reduced array...

Answer (score 1):

Make shape2 grab a new color until its different from shape1

```
onTriggered: {
     shape1.color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]
     do {
          shape2.color = colorArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]
     } while(shape1.color === shape2.color);
}
```

Comment: You may be causing unnecessary re-evaluation of property bindings and possible UI flickering by setting color property directly in a loop, see perf tip here how to fix that: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html#property-bindings